# How to deactivate Xdebug way to dump data in Twig's {{ dump() }} in Symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, twig, xdebug, dump

I am using Symfony 4 on PHP 7.1.14 with Xdebug enabled and `html_errors=on`.

When I use `{{ dump() }}` function in my twig, data printed on the screen is hard to read because of poor Xdebug formatting ([ugly dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzU7N.png)). It's also not dumping objects, which is necessary in my case (I see them as an object and can't see their properties).

I remember using this function in Symfony 3 with PHP 7.0.13 and the output was presented as the cool black area with foldable data ([cool dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JOQo.png)). All PHP options and extensions were the same.

Is there any way to force using Twig dump?

[image: ugly dump]

[image: cool dump]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Symfony4, 'dump' appears to be in Flex's 'debug-pack'

```
composer req debug-pack
```

Answer (score 1):

I think for Symfony4  you have to use the `composer require var-dumper` package.

[Symfony Docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/debug.html)