# Twig Debugger show real var_dump instead of the twig debug output

Tags: symfony, debugging, twig

Normally, when debugging with 'dump()' in twig, I get those tiny black little boxes, in which I can see my output,and open objects by clicking on an arrow. I don't know what I have changed, but now I get real var_dumps, means, I see full objects with 1000 lines instead of the black boxes.

Does anybody know, how to turn back the "old" behaviour?

Comment: Symfony version?

Comment: Perhaps [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49511593/how-to-deactivate-xdebug-way-to-dump-data-in-twigs-dump-in-symfony-4)

Comment: Oh, sorry, it is symfony 4.2.4

Comment: Yes, the relation is true. I have xdebug running on the system, too, but nothing works. It still displays the xdebug dump instead of symfonys twig dump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, one point which was missing is:

It is important to set the environment to DEV, in my case, we are using antother environment called LOCAL. If I switch to DEV, everything works like described by @DarkBee and @AythaNzt:

- `composer require var-dumper`
- set `html_errors on` in php.ini
- set `fastcgi_param VAR_DUMPER_FORMAT html;` in nginx

Currently I don't know where the difference between these two environments, since local is a plain copy from dev, but anyway: it works.

Comment: just set twig debug ON for the new Env.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install:

```
composer require --dev symfony/var-dumper
```

You need to have `php bin/console server:run` previously and then, open another terminal and if you want to see it directly in the terminal, run:

```
php bin/console server:dump
```

or

```
php bin/console server:dump --format=html > dump.html
```

if you want to generate a html for opening and close object by clicking.

For more info, check: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html

Comment: Strange, nothgin works, I already set the Env-Var  "VAR_DUMPER_FORMAT html;", but nothinh works. 
I am using docker, instead of symfonys server.